# LEFT OUTER JOIN with a WHERE clause on the first table

Tags: php, mysql, outer-join

I want to `SELECT` a some rows from a table, but these rows must satisfy a condition like `column = value`. Here's my `SELECT` statement:

```
$query = "SELECT t1.title, t1.introtext, t2.jr_street, t2.jr_city, 
    t2.jr_state, t2.jr_postalcode, t2.jr_country, t3.created, t3.name, 
    t3.title, t3.comments, t4.ave 
FROM $table1 t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN $table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.contentid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN $table3 t3 ON t1.id = t3.pid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN $table4 t4 ON t1.id = t4.reviewid
";
```

I tried adding a `WHERE` clause after the `FROM` statement, but I am getting an SQL syntax error.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `WHERE` clause after the last `JOIN`?

Comment: What is the WHERE clause you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I have to guess your problem. Next time you should give us your full example a the exact error. Did you try something like this?

```
$value = (int) $_POST['value'];
$query = "SELECT t1.title, t1.introtext, t2.jr_street, t2.jr_city, t2.jr_state,
t2.jr_postalcode, t2.jr_country, t3.created, t3.name, t3.title, 
t3.comments, t4.ave FROM $table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN $table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.contentid
LEFT OUTER JOIN $table3 t3 ON t1.id = t3.pid
LEFT OUTER JOIN $table4 t4 ON t1.id = t4.reviewid
WHERE t2.column = ".$value."
AND t1.catid=8";
```

I just guessed you want to select from table2 ;) You have to fill in the right table and column. Also i put the category selection in the where clause since imho this makes it more readable.

Please make absolutely sure that all variables like `$value` (and the tables) are save for usage in a query, for example that `$value` is an integer and the tables are explicitly set in your code and are not a user input. You can read more about SQL-Injections here:

- http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-Injection
- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
- [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)